# Mark Duplicated Rows & Add Range Numbers for Duplicate Rows, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Data:

```
Data = pd.DataFrame([['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['4', '3', '2', '1'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['4', '3', '2', '1'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['3', '5', '2', '6'], ['10', '9', '8', '7'], ['5', '6', '7', '3'], ['10', '9', '8', '7']], columns=['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4'])
```

Marking Duplicate Rows:

```
Data['Is_Dup'] = Data[['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4']].duplicated(keep=False).astype(int)
```

Data:

[image]

Expected Results: I want to generate extra field called Dup_Ser, here range values needs to add for duplicate rows.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is sorting bay all columns with `Is_Dup` descending and then add new column with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), added `1` and multiple by `Data['Is_Dup']` for `0` for not duplicated values:

```
cols = ['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4']
Data['Is_Dup'] = Data[cols].duplicated(keep=False).astype(int)

Data = Data.sort_values(['Is_Dup'] + cols, ascending=[False] + [True] * len(cols))
Data['Dup_Ser'] = Data.groupby(cols).cumcount().add(1).mul(Data['Is_Dup'])
print (Data)
   F1 F2 F3 F4  Is_Dup  Dup_Ser
0   1  2  3  4       1        1
2   1  2  3  4       1        2
4   1  2  3  4       1        3
6  10  9  8  7       1        1
8  10  9  8  7       1        2
1   4  3  2  1       1        1
3   4  3  2  1       1        2
5   3  5  2  6       0        0
7   5  6  7  3       0        0
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want (*Dup_Ser* column) is provided by *cumcount()* function within
*grouby*. But to group duplicated sets of rows together, you need also *ngroup()*
function.

To sum up, use the following code:

```
gr = Data[Data.Is_Dup == 1].groupby(['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4'], sort=False)
Data['gNo'] = gr.ngroup()
Data['Dup_Ser'] = gr.cumcount() + 1
del gr
Data = Data.sort_values('gNo').drop(columns='gNo')
Data.Dup_Ser = Data.Dup_Ser.fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```